# Which machine learning algorithm is appropriate for predicting a vector?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, machine-learning

I have a very large set of animal migration data, consisting of many series of vectors - each series is basically a path of a single animal. The dataset I'm using consists of 244 of these series.

[image: Blue vectors are between pink points, pink points are snapshots of an individual animal's location]

I want to train a predictive model so that when it is given a collection of these series and a map of environmental variables, such as a map of ocean surface temperature, it can output a new collection of these series.

My question is which machine learning algorithm would be optimal for this kind of prediction - I was looking into multinomial logistic regression, but that is for categorical data. I want the algorithm to develop a model that thinks at a point with an ocean surface temperature of 20˚C, an animal will travel along a vector with a magnitude of 35km and an angle of 34˚'.

I was also looking into using the random forest algorithm, but that seems to be more for classification than forecasting. Does the algorithm I'm thinking of exist? Thanks so much.

EDIT: My particular question is not how to fit this data with a particular ML method, but is there an ML algorithm that can predict a new vector (in polar form) given an old vector and an environmental variable at the tail of that vector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the random forest algorithm to predict vectors](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47769/using-the-random-forest-algorithm-to-predict-vectors)

Comment: It looks like you are basically re-posting your prior question, but with a little bit of a different emphasis.  Please don't do that -- we don't want duplicates, and this is not an appropriate way to try to gather more attention to your question.  Instead, you should edit your old question by clicking the "edit" link underneath it, to make it reflect what you want to ask.

Comment: 1. I think one thing that is missing from this question is how you will evaluate the output of your model.  What criteria/objective function/metrics will you use to evaluate the output of a proposed model?  2. It sounds like you want more of a generative model rather than a discriminative model.  A random forest is a discriminative model rather than a generative model, so not the obvious approach.  So, my advice is to spend some time with a ML textbook looking at different kinds of generative models.

Comment: @D.W. What do you mean by 'evaluate the output' of my model? - I plan to test the models accuracy by feeding in temperature data that already has a known migration pattern, then comparing the generated outcomes with those current day migration patterns. Also, thanks.

Comment: @jeshaitan, can you explain how you will do the comparison, and how you will quantify the degree of match?  It's very unlikely that the output of the machine learning model will match the observations exactly, so how do you plan to quantify the degree to which it matches?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I'm going to go about comparing them. @D.W.

Comment: @D.W. Since my data ultimately forms many directed graph, I think I might try and use some sort of graph similarity algorithm http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965907001012

Comment: @D.W. I feel like this is a pretty complex problem, however, and there are many different definitions of similarity. Do you know of any similarity measures that would fit this set?

Comment: formulating the input/ output is a basic 1st step of ML independent of algorithms & this is not done yet here clearly. suggest drop by [chat] for help

Comment: We can't tell you what similarity metric makes sense for your application; only you can tell that.  Your first step, before you should start thinking about machine learning algorithms, is to specify the problem: to identify a metric to quantify the usefulness of a prediction (e.g., its accuracy).  I don't recommend searching around for random notions of graph similarity.  Instead, I'd recommend you start with how you are going to use the predictions, and use that to try to come up with a way to quantify the error/inaccuracy in a candidate prediction.

Comment: I don't think any of the proposed methods will suite this, as they are engineered to predict a scalar/categorical output. The 1st step would be to decided on a measure of "similarity". I think the first sensible measure would be akin to Frobinius norm $|| Y - \hat{Y} ||^2_F$ where $Y$ is your set of vector-labels (a matrix) and $\hat{Y}$ is the predicted matrix, determined by $XB$. This can be estimated using traditional linear regression methods once you vectorize your matrices. More sophisticated approaches that incorporate priors to regularize $B$ can be found under "multi-task learning".

Comment: @NicholasMancuso, thanks so much for this suggestion, but what is XB?

Comment: $X$ is your feature matrix, and $B$ is your parameter matrix. This should equivalent to ordinary least squares with objective $||vec(Y) - vec(XB)||_2^2$. Once you've fit your model ($\hat{B}$), you can predict new instances as $Y_{pred} = X_{new}\hat{B}$.

Comment: In order to validate your model, just perform k-fold cross-validation (with k=5, or 10, or whatever) and measure $r^2$.

Comment: The data set you have sounds far too small for most machine learning methods.  Have you considered classical time series models?